# Binding object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Binding error in spring and jsp, I would appreciate if someone could help.

I have proper getter and setter of these attribute,

```
private int sydinv;
@NotNull(message="You must specify the inventory in Melbourne warehouse")
private int melinv;
```

And when I use them in jsp file, error message says "Bean property 'sydinv' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products/save" method = "post" commandName="product">
<label>Title
<form:input  path="title" /> <form:errors path="title"/></label>
<br/>
<label> Description 
<form:input type = "text" path= "description"/></label>
<br/>
<label>Price
<form:input  path= "price" /><form:errors path="price"/></label>
<label>Image
<form:input  path= "imageUrl" /><form:errors path="imageUrl"/></label>
<label>sydinv
<form:input  path= "sydinv" /><form:errors path="sydinv"/></label>
<label>Inventory
<form:input  path= "inventory" /><form:errors path="inventory"/></label>
<form:input type="hidden" path="productId"/>
<br/>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
<br/>
<input type = "reset" />
</form:form>
```

And here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{productId}")
public String edit(@PathVariable int productId, Model model){
    //add your code here to find a product based on its id
    //and put it in the model
    Product product = pdao.getProductById(productId);
    System.out.println("@@"+product.getSydInv()+"##"+product.getMelInv());

    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    return "product";
}
```

The jsp file can read all of the attribute except **syd_inv**, can anyone gives me some hint? Cheers

Comment: What is the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

> Bean property 'sydinv' is not readable

here your `sydinv`  is written in simple but your getter method is pointing to a `SydInv` writen in capital `getSydInv()` .i think your `getter` and `setter` methods are  wrong 
change it to

```
setsydinv(int sydinv){this.sydinv = sydinv}
int getsydinv(){return sydinv}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I change the name in parameter list same as the class attribute, it works, thanks so much for you help.